# AcceptButton как изменить?

Tags: c#

Необходимо, чтобы при нахождении фокуса на одном из полей, программа меняла AcceptButton. Пока что-то не получается. При этом имеется несколько кнопок. Для каждого поля свой AcceptButton. Если что-то не понятно уточняйте.

Comment: Что значит "изменить AcceptButton" ?

Comment: В смысле изменить кнопку на форме, которая будет отвечать за AcceptButton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По эвенту [Enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.enter.aspx) на "одном из полей", подсовываешь [AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton(v=VS.100).aspx)'у нужную кнопку, или свой контрол реализующий IButtonControl. Как то вот так.

З.Ы. Вторая ссылка с примером.